# failed to get values of XML elements in pugixml using node.value()

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

I have below simple XML template in my C++ source code. Within below code block I need to get values for `<scannerID>` and `<subscannerID>`. both elements are children of pugixml document root.

```
xml_document doc;
xml_parse_result r;
std::string sXml = "<inArgs><scannerID>1</scannerID><subScannerID>2</subScannerID></inArgs>";


r = doc.load_buffer(sXml.c_str(), sXml.length());
if (!r) {
    return false;
}


xml_node root = doc.child("inArgs");

if (!root) {
    return false;
}

std::cout << "root = " << root.name() << std::endl;

xml_node scanner_node = root.child("scannerID");
if (scanner_node) {
    std::cout << "scannerID = " << scanner_node.name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "scannerID = " << scanner_node.value() << std::endl;
}

xml_node sub_scanner_node = root.child("subscannerID");
if (scanner_node) {
    std::cout << "sub_scanner_node = " << sub_scanner_node.name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sub_scanner_node = " << sub_scanner_node.value() << std::endl;
}
```

this code portion giving an output like below. I can get the node's names correctly but failed to retrieve the values.

Out put: values are empty strings.

```
root = inArgs
scannerID = scannerID
scannerID = 
subscannerID = subscannerID
subscannerID =
```

***Edited to add modification for the approach in the answer***

```
node = root.child("scannerID");
if (!node) {
    return false;
}

std::cout << "nodeName = %s" << node.name() << std::endl;
std::cout << "text value: " << node.child_value() << std::endl;
```

but still the output is the same. I saw something different while reading the documents in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data is in the pcdata child of your element_nodes.

Try `scanner_node.child_value()`

see the [Getting node data](http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/manual/access.html#manual.access.nodedata) section for further examples and explanation.

see [node_element](http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/manual/dom.html#node_element)

see [node_pcdata](http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/manual/dom.html#node_pcdata)

Comment: Thanks for helping on this. I referred to above documents and did some changes (to add `node.child_value()`) but still I'm getting an empty string. meanwhile I saw new class call xml_text and some member methods but I am not able to use it because of errors (cannot resolve xml_text member name)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BAM9qzY9 

I compiled the above and the output is correct. Anything else going on?

Comment: Oh, that means I have something wrong. I will try 1 more time. Thanks

Comment: Moved to [Github](https://github.com/zeux/pugixml) (links in original post are invalid).